# Using ARG and ENV in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I am learning how to use ARG and ENV in Dockerfiles.
I have this simple Dockerfile:

```
ARG my_arg
ARG other_arg=other_default

FROM centos:7

ENV MY_ENV $my_arg
ENV OTHER_ENV $other_arg

CMD echo "$MY_ENV $OTHER_ENV"
```

When I build it:
`docker build --build-arg my_arg=my_value`

And run it:
`docker run <resulting-image>`

I do not see the expected output, which would be

```
my_value other_default
```

Instead, I see the empty string.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In a Dockerfile, each `FROM` line starts a new image, and generally resets the build environment.  If your image needs to specify `ARG`s, they need to come *after* the `FROM` line; if it's a multi-stage build, they need to be repeated in each image as required.  `ARG` before the first `FROM` are only useful to allow variables in the `FROM` line, but can't be used otherwise.

This is further discussed under [Understand how ARG and FROM interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact) in the Dockerfile documentation.

```sh
FROM centos:7

# _After_ the FROM line
ARG my_arg
ARG other_arg=other_default
...
```

Comment: Basically, I got confused by "ARG is the only instruction that may precede FROM in the Dockerfile.", simply interpreting it as a hint that you'd want to put `ARG` in front of `FROM` for stylistic reasons, but I did not click the link.

Comment: What about when you pass `ARG`s using the `--build-arg` option on the command line?  Do those get wiped out when Docker hits `FROM`?

Comment: You need to both declare an `ARG` and pass the `--build-arg` option.  If you've declared `ARG` everywhere its needed, each use should get the same value from the command line.

Answer (score 19):

At least since `20.10.2`, `ARG`s can be passed from outside the `FROM` line onwards, all you need to do is insert another `ARG` with the same name after the `FROM`:

```
ARG my_arg
ARG other_arg=other_default

FROM centos:7

# These need to be re-stated here to use the ARGs above.
ARG my_arg
ARG other_arg # This will be populated with the default value 'other_default'.

ENV MY_ENV $my_arg
ENV OTHER_ENV $other_arg

CMD echo "$MY_ENV $OTHER_ENV"
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for - thank you!