# Large Set of Configuration Values during Deployment [Azure Deployments/Releases]

Tags: docker, azure-devops, deployment

I have a larger set of configuration values during on-prem deployments for our customers.
I want to point out that we are using Azure Deployment Agents.

Currently we are using Deployment/Release variables, which than are basically set as environment variables on the target machine, which than again are used by our docker-compose files to set environment variables inside of the docker containers, which than are used by the application running inside of the container.

So it's quite some piping happening and we need to touch multiple places for a new variable to be usable for the application ( Release Pipeline, docker-compose files, Application ).

This is straight forward but as the amount of variables increases this just gets more and more chaotic. And without some kind of seperators and custom parsing we are not going to be able to have a list of some "multi value objects". This is not needed yet but might come in the future.

Is there some recommended way of distributing ?
I would still like to have a easy way of editing configuration values if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To manage the variable easily, you can consider below options, change one place and apply to all, across multiple pipelines.

Option1: [variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic).

Option2: [Yaml template to reuse variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#variable-reuse).

Variable on DevOps pipeline will automatically set as environment on Deployment group, you can map it to docker in dockerfile, check link [Using ARG and ENV in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450479/using-arg-and-env-in-dockerfile).